# Converting Unix time stamp to dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss

Tags: excel, unix-timestamp

I have a column that holds Unix timestamps at C1, and I am looking for the formula to create a new column that converts the timestamp to dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss.

Here is a sample of the timestamp:

```
1409502202
```

Comment: Do you want `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss` specifically, or do you just want Excel to interpret it as a general date value? This would allow you to perform date calculations on it.

Comment: I want dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss! Because I'm mainly coding on JavaScript and I just want to check my output values :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are going to have to provide some conversion from the UNIX (aka POSIX) timestamp to an Excel Date format. Typically this is performed by dividing the timestamp by 86,400 (number of seconds in a day) and adding 25,569 (number of days from 01-Jan-1900 to 01-Jan-1970). With a raw value that is in synch with the Excel date/time numerical system, the [TEXT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXT-function-4B46E545-E612-4C84-AC23-EDFA68007945) can create the date/time.

```
=text(c1/86400 + 25569, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss")  'yields 31/08/2014 16:23:22
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! By the way, how come when I'm using Java and JavaScript I need to multiply my timestamp by 1000, but I don't now? Mine's a 10 digit unix timestamp :-)

Comment: UNIX (or POSIX) time and Javascript are simply two different time formats that happen to increment differently by a factor of 1000. An increment of 1 in Javascript time is equal to 1000 in UNIX time. Another way of looking at it is that an increment of 1 in UNIX time was equal to 1ms in Javascript time. Conversely, the Buddhist and Gregorian calendar each increment by 1 day but start 543 years apart.

Comment: I see, I understand much better now! Thanks so much for your help! God bless :-)