# Making Sense of Excel Calculations with HH:MM:SS

Tags: javascript, excel, math, excel-formula, modulus

I am in the middle of converting some excel calculations to Javascript.

I encountered a calculation in excel that calculates a value using a input value with a format of HH:MM:SS that doesn't seem to make sense.

Firstly this is the formula I'm trying to make sense of:

```
=MOD((Jataka!$C$60*24*2.5*5*30), 360)
```

In the above formula, the cell inside `Jataka!$C$60` has the value of `21:11:29` and the cell has the Cell Format of Custom `[h]:mm:ss`

Here are the results of the excel calculations if broken down to smaller steps:

Since `Jataka!$C$60` = `21:11:29` and `24*2.5*5*30` = `9000`

`(Jataka!$C$60*24*2.5*5*30)` according to excel equals `190723:29:53`

If you then change the Cell Format of the cell that holds the result of calculation of `190723:29:53` to a Cell Format of `Number`, the Number equivalent of `190723:29:53` according to excel is `7946.81`.

and if you take `7946.81` and apply excel's MOD function to it with the divisor of `360` you get the calculated and final value of `26.81242183`.

In other words: `=MOD(7946.81, 360)` = `26.81242183`

Above are what's calculated in excel.

I am trying to get my head around this calculation and here is my line of thought.....

I am assuming that `21:11:29` means: hour is 21, minute is 11, and seconds is 29.

Therefore I change hour min sec to a decimal equivalent.
`21:11:29` in decimal is suppose to be `21.191388888888888`
Then I get `21.191388888888888` and multiply `24*2.5*5*30` or `9000` to it.
`21.191388888888888` x `24*2.5*5*30` or `9000` = `190722.5`.

At this point I notice that my calculation of `190722.5` is different from excel calculation for both the raw `hh:mm:ss` format and the `Number` equivalent format.

In the above excel calculation, the raw `hh:mm:ss` format was `190723:29:53`.
If you convert `190723:29:53` to decimal you get`190723.49805555557`

`190723.49805555557` is different from our calculation of `190722.5`.

The Number equivalent format of `190723:29:53` is `7946.81` according to excel.

`7946.81` is also different from out calculation of `190722.5`.

So even at this point, we are already getting different intermediate results....
What is the reason for this???

How does excel convert a value like `21:11:29` to a `Number` ????

If I continue with my calculation by doing the MOD of 360 I get
`=MOD(190722.5, 360)` = `282.5`.

However in the excel file I am basing my calculation in the result is `26.81` which is based on:
`=MOD(7946.81, 360)` = `26.81242183`

What am I not understanding here?
What step am I missing?

How does excel convert a value like `21:11:29` to a `Number` ????

Even if I first convert `21:11:29` to a `Number` in excel, I get the value of `0.88`.

I believe these are the 2 important questions to solve this problem:

1.) What formula does excel use to multiply `21:11:29` by a `Number`?

2.) and how does excel convert values with a format of HH:MM:SS like `21:11:29` to a `Number`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Therefore I change hour min sec to a decimal equivalent. 21:11:29 in decimal is suppose to be 21.191388888888888

`21:11:29` or `TIME(21, 11, 29)` is NOT `21.191388888888888`.

A date in Excel is **1** for every day past 31-Dec-1899. Today happens to be 42,413. Time is considered a decimal portion of a day so today at noon was 42,413.5 and today at 8:00 pm was 42,413.83333.

Your time of 21:11:29 (with no date component) is equal to ~0.882974537, not 21.191388888888. If you multiply it by 24 (the number of hours in a day) then it is 21.191388888888 because you have converted the hours from fractions of a day (¹⁄₂₄) to integers (1).

Hopefully that will help make it understandable. tbh, I cannot figure out why you are multiplying by 9000 nor what your end purpose actually is.

Comment: Hi, do you have a Code Snippet of a Javascript function that returns the Date Number of a Excel Date and Time?  Where can I find it?  Thank you...

Comment: To deal with Javascript time as raw numbers vs. Excel dates and time you will need to convert. Javascript time is closer to a POSIX time. See [Converting Unix time stamp to dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33773149#33773295) for an explanation of the conversion factors. Javascript addendum is in the comments.