# Converting UNIX Timestamp to IST Timestamp

Tags: excel, excel-formula, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I want to convert unix timestamp to IST Timestamp in excel(excel 2013), I have  tried the following command for "1432116763", but unable to get proper format, seeking assistance for the same.

```
(unixTimestamp/86400)+25569+(-9/24)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting Unix time stamp to dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33773149/converting-unix-time-stamp-to-dd-mm-yyyy-hhmmss/33773295#33773295).

Comment: If the above link has helped, you may want to consider self-answering this question. It would help to see your take on handling the time zone differential. You will be to mark it as the accepted answer after 48 hours.

Comment: indeed it was helpful but instead of explicitly mentioning "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss" you can just format your column into the date timestamp, which will reduce  your length of command

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The linked answer was put forth that way because of a special platform transfer to javascript for comparison.