# Converting a (16-Digit) Timestamp in Excel

Tags: json, excel, excel-formula, timestamp

I've got a small fun puzzle for you.

It has me 100% stumped! After 2-hours of trial-and-error + Google searches, I'm asking for help :)

Timestamp:1393878630947498

What is the excel formula to convert that to a Date/Time?

I know for a FACT the actual Date/Time is: May 9, 2017, 10:21 PM

Many thanks!

Comment: If that was a POSIX datetime the result would be 03-Mar-2014 20:30:31. See [Converting Unix time stamp to dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33773149/converting-unix-time-stamp-to-dd-mm-yyyy-hhmmss/33773295#33773295).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting Unix time stamp to dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33773149/converting-unix-time-stamp-to-dd-mm-yyyy-hhmmss)

Answer (score 0):

Take the big integer and multiply it by:

```
 0.000000000030752269457537
```

then format the product as *date/time*

[image]

**NOTE:**

This simple relationship is only valid if the two time/date forms have the same starting point.

Comment: fwiw, anyone can arrive at a predetermined result with simple maths given a single example. It would be interesting to see if the same conversion proved true over several inputs and expected results but the op has been short of retrospect in that matter.